# Kii not working on unity android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kiicloud

I want to use Kii(Cloud) as backend for my Unity Android game. 
Everything works fine on my computer. I added some users, a few global buckets and used queries to filter information from them. The problems start when I try to start the .apk on my phone. 
The app itself starts, but it never gets past a grey screen. 
The unity scene never loads. 
Investigating it further, even an empty unity project with the unity-cloud-sdk-3.2.10.unitypackage imported does not seem to load the first scene. Just a grey screen.

I am using Unity 2018.1.0b13 Personal Edition.
Tested on physical OnePlus One with Android Cyanogen Mod
and emulated Nexus 5 with standard Android.

Does anyone know that is wrong here?
I posted this exact same question on their own forum, but the last post there is from september 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the KiiCloud Forum

---

Hi,

I confirmed that unity-cloud-sdk-3.2.10.unitypackage works properly on the android real device.
My env is:
Unity Personal Edition Version 2017.4.0f1
Galaxy S8 (Android7.0)
ASUS Zenfone3 (Android7.0)

Did you get any error messages?
Please ensure that your project is configured properly.
http://docs.kii.com/en/guides/cloudsdk/unity/quickstart/install-sdk/

Best regards,

---

So basically Unity 2018 does not work properly if you try to build for android.
http://community.kii.com/t/kii-not-working-on-unity-android-build/1678